# How to manage timeout in OrchardCommandHandler

Tags: orchardcms

We created a class that inherit from DefaultOrchardCommandHandler to add new command line. Our process take 8 to 12 minutes depending of the environment. We are suspecting that we hit a timeout at 10 minutes because:

1. if we split the job in 3 parts, everything runs fine
2. when we check the log, the last operation before the error is around 9 minutes 40 seconds

Is there a way to change a setting to increase the timeout from 10 minutes to 15 minutes for orchard.exe? We are using orchard 1.5.1 .

Thank you, Have a great day!
Sebastien

**Error**

```
The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
```

Comment: We changed the connection string time out without any success. In SQL profiler, we can see tons of queries responding under 2 secondes. May be it the nhibernate transaction scope that timeout after 10 minutes? Not sure where to look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found out that as soon that I override the parameter maxTimeout with a default value of 10 minutes in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config, .NET start respecting the timeout value in the transactionScope constructor in C#.

Thank you all!